# Using Answering Machine Detection with Twilio Proxy

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

We're using Twilio Proxy for one-to-one masked communications. We want our users to be able to text and call each other, but have their identities protected.

This all works well, except in the case where the call isn't picked up, and the user's answering machine picks up. If they say their name in their recorded message, obviously the anonymity isn't there. We'd like to detect when the answering machine picks up, and either end the call or play a recorded message in place of the voicemail.

Is there any way to do this with the proxy service? Maybe we can intercept the call, then update the call (but it appears this only supports TwiML, which doesn't support AMD) or intercept the call and create a new call (but I think this would ring again for the caller, which isn't ideal). To be honest, I expected this to be a standard feature of Twilio Proxy, but it doesn't look like it is.

Thanks!